# Rotate igraph layout for bipartite networks from vertical to horizontal orientation

Tags: r, igraph

I have created a bipartite network with vertical orientation with:

```
edgelist <- read.table(text="Person    Event
                         Amy       football
                         Bob       picnic
                         Sam       artshow", 
                       header=TRUE)
igraph <- graph.data.frame(edgelist)

V(igraph)$type <- V(igraph)$name %in% edgelist[,1]
plot(igraph, vertex.label=V(igraph)$Name, vertex.size=7,vertex.label.dist=2, layout=layout_as_bipartite)
```

I was wondering if I can create the same plot with horizontal orientation and the node names next to each node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the original layout matrix, one can use the following code, after one have set the type of the graph:

```
LO <- layout_as_bipartite(igraph)
```

Now it has the correct coordinates for the bipartite plotting, but it plots the graph in two rows. To plot it in the desired orientation, one can flip the X and Y coordinates, by the backward indexing of the matrix.

```
plot(igraph, vertex.label=V(igraph)$Name, vertex.size=7,vertex.label.dist=2, layout=LO[,2:1])
```

**Edit**

I forgot that you want to reposition the labels. Fortunately, you have set the **$type** parameter as the indicator of the edges' tail nodes. You can use the **vertex.label.degree** argument of the plot function. Multiplying the mentioned logical vector attribute with *pi* has solved that problem too. So the position of the tails' labels are rotated by *pi*, while on the right, you have the labels rotated by 0. I have also plotted the labels a bit further from the nodes.

```
plot(igraph, vertex.label=V(igraph)$Name,
 vertex.size=7, vertex.label.dist=3, layout=LO[,2:1],
 vertex.label.degree = pi*V(igraph)$type)
```

[image: Updated bipartite horizontal plot]